# Create small projects on Angular2 and then join them as one project

Tags: angular, projects-and-solutions

I have a question of Angular2, I have a web site that is quite old and I want to translate this old project to Angular2, it is the best idea to create different small projects in the transition and then join them in one project?

And if it so, where I can find a good example to avoid any disasters in the future.

Thanks for the information.

Comment: Why not create components/modules and integrate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular NgModules](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules) system is pretty good for this. You can create separated smaller app modules, which you can connect with a root module, just as a tree.

I think you should avoid using templates for this task, as it is crucial to understand the fundamentations of Angular modularization.

For example, when you create a new app with the Anguar CLI, `ng new my-app`, it creates you a Root, basic module called AppComponent. That can be the root Module for your application, and you can create different other modules with the other [CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-module) command `ng generate module [module name here]` - one for each subsection of the page you want to refactor.

So, look up Angular modules, maybe start with the [official documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules).